# Force Arch boot to specific GPU

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, grub2, pci-passthrough

**Arch Linux** - kernel 4.13.12-1 (x64)

**Bootloader** - Grub 2

**Window Manager**: I3-wm.

**Gpus**: AMD 570 (Passthrough), 1080Ti(Passthrough), 1050TI (Host)

**Misc**: Dual-Monitor

I have three GPUs in my machine, the first two of which are being used for passthrough to a guest via [vfio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Using_vfio-pci).  The third is used for display on the host itself.

Arch always defaults to the first GPU when booting, which was fine when I only had two GPUs (one for the host and one for pass-through). However, I just added a third GPU now.  So, the 1080 and 570 (first two slots) are being used for passthrough. The last slot, the 1050ti, is for the host.  They do have to be in this order as the first slots are PCIEx16

**Question:** As it stands, Arch tries to boot using the first slot, and freezes.  How can I force it to boot specifically to the third gpu?  Do I need to black list cards?

After some research, I was able to find a couple of similar posts, but nothing has worked for me so far, but I may not be employing the solutions correctly:

[Booting to the second GPU on RedHat](https://www.redhat.com/archives/vfio-users/2016-August/msg00030.html)

[Using Fbcon:Map<>](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt)

Thanks!

Comment: that first link did it for me, you should have posted about how you implemented it - perhaps you missed something